# Set the textbox value of usercontrol from Main winForm Button

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I have a main Form 'frmMaster' that contains on one button 'btnSet',
inside this main form I put a panel control contains on usercontrol,
on this user control there is one textbox,
my question is how to set the value of this textbox when I click on the button 'btnset' from main form,
for example: when I click on 'btnset' from main form, the value of textbox on the usercontrol will be "Welcome"

In userControl I Put:

```
Public Property TextBoxTxt () As String
    Get
        Return txtText1.Text 
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        txtText1.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

On Main Form I Put inside button:

```
 Dim uc As New ucControl1         
    uc.txtText1.Text= "Welcome!"
```

Comment: have you got any code to show? i cant understand your question.

Comment: No you must write : uc.TextBoxTxt= "Welcome!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UserControl Must be like :

```
Public Class UserControl1
        Private Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        End Sub
        Public Property TextBoxTxt() As String
            Get
                Return txtText1.Text
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                txtText1.Text = value
            End Set
        End Property
    End Class
```

In you MainForm add a button "btnSet" and a Panel "Panel1" ,so your code inside MainForm must be like :

```
Public Class frmMaster

    Private Sub btnSet_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSet.Click
        Dim uc As New UserControl1
        uc.txtText1.Text = "Welcome!"
        Panel1.Controls.Add(uc)
    End Sub

    Private Sub frmMaster_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub
End Class
```

I have create a simple [exemple](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/e12109d37dfcd7ff057c43eb7f7cf99520160511140746/3877ea#) for you

Comment: @Jassimi if you have already add a controle in your MainForm you should just rwite  ucControl1.TextBoxTxt="Welcome!" ,have a look at my second answer , it's without " Dim uc As New ucControl1 "

Comment: If I'm writing like that, I will get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Ok @Jassim i have edit my answer how i show you  Step by step .and here is a link for an exemple

Answer (score 1):

In the user control:

```
Public Property TextBoxTxt () As String
    Get
        Return Me.textbox.Text 
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        Me.txtebox.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

In your  even click of the button 'btnset' :

```
    Private Sub btnset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnset.Click
             Dim uc As New MyUserControl

            uc.TextBoxTxt ="Welcome!"

        End Sub
```

Comment: Try just frmMaster.UserControlName.TextBox1.Text= "Welcome!"

Comment: I put it in my question

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a `public` property to the usercontrol, e.g.

```
Public Property TextBoxMessage As String
    Get
        Return textbox.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        textbox.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Then you can display a message from inside your frmMaster:

```
usercontrol.TextBoxMessage = "Welcome!"
```

Comment: Since Beldi has posted the same answer (but in VB) and since you are having a similar issue with their code, I'll leave you in Beldi's hands. :)

Comment: @Ulric when i open tne answer page for writen my answer ,it's in in the meantime that you have posted your answer,Sorry!

Comment: @Beldi Hi. Although my C# version is useful, your VB version is more appropriate for the question. So it is all good. :) {edit} But now my post has been translated into VB.